# Callback for form submission (with jQuery)

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, callback, submit

I have a modal window that presents a form to users. The form includes one or more file uploads as well. Therefore I cannot submit the form with ajax.

At the moment I'm doing a standard submit with a submit button. When the form is submitted (which takes a few seconds in general), a PDF is generated and sent back for download (i.e. the Content-Disposition: attachment header), to force the download. Once the upload of the form data has completed, I need to close the modal window. If I call the close method straight way the submission never completes and the file download is never triggered (I think this is because the modal window is removed from the DOM). I can set a timeout, but there could be n number of images, so the time it takes to upload is unpredictable (and relative to the number of uploads).

I've looked at the jQuery form plugin (http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload), but apparently it uses an iframe to upload files, so I'm not sure if it will achieve what I need.

Thanks for any help,

Dom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewritten after rereading the question. Here's what I'd try:

1. Serialize the form and make it the return value from the dialog, i.e. pass the data back to the page.
2. Close the dialog
3. Submit the serialized form

Comment: The file is streamed, so I cant do a GET on the file. I know that you cant do this with ajax, which is why I was originally asking.

I obviously understand the need to call close within the callback, it was more about whether there was a window or document event I can bind to when the file download begins. 

Ive tested the form plugin, but the post-submit callback never gets triggered. The pre-submit executes fine, the form submits fine, the file downloads, but nothing happens when after the form submits (i.e. no post-submit callback).

Comment: Ah, reread the question and realized you were doing it as a synchronous POST. I guess I just skipped over the first sentence. And now I see why you wanted a timeout. Edited response.

Comment: Cant serialize file objects :(

Answer (score 1):

The [Form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload) you mentioned should work - why do you suspect it won't?

Comment: I've used the Form plugin for uploads myself. Hidden iframe targeting is standard practice for "ajax" uploading.

Comment: I debugged the form plugin, and I can get the callback working, however the modal is destroyed too fast, so the request never finishes and the file doesnt download

Comment: @Dominic Can't you hide the modal instead of destroying it?